# Identify type of recordset

Tags: vb6, ado

How can we determine the type of a recordset as a normal or hierachical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan through the Fields collection in the Recordset, checking each Field's Type property.  If you find any where .Type = adChapter then it is a hierarchical Recordset.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a difference in the recordset object itself.  The difference is in the literal definition/organization of the contents of the recordset:

> A hierarchical recordset is a
>   recordset that is comprised of a
>   hierarchy of records. For example, any
>   recordset with a parent/child
>   relationship can be defined as a
>   hierarchical recordset. Unlike a join
>   which basically duplicates all of the
>   parent data for each child, each
>   record in a hierarchical recordset
>   contains the set of parent fields and
>   one field which is the child
>   recordset.

**Source & more info:**
http://www.insteptech.com/techLibrary/vbClassic/vb6_hierarchical.htm